# Difference between right and inner join

Tags: sql, join

I have a table Table_1:

```
D1----D2
123----NULL
1a3----NULL
35s----NULL
tg45---NULL
```

If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1 A
RIGHT JOIN(
  SELECT * 
  FROM Table_1 B
  WHERE
  SUBSTRING(B.D1,len(B.D1)-1,100) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') C
ON A.D1=C.D1
WHERE CONVERT(INT,(SUBSTRING(A.D1,len(A.D1)-1,100)))<25;
```

I get as a result of a single record:

```
123----NULL----123----NULL
```

It's OK.

If I change right join to inner join then I get an error:

> *Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>  Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'a3' to data type int.*

Can you explain why this is happening ?

Comment: You don't get to control what row are evaluated.   Only what rows are returned.  You have an (SUBSTRING(A.D1,len(A.D1)-1,100)) that is not and integer.

Comment: I guess you mean, "if I change inner join to right join"?

Comment: No. When I have right join it's working. It's just interesting.

Comment: I tried that and its strange that how come the where clause considers the record which will not be in part of inner join condition, still keep working on that, will update if I found something.

Answer (score 0):

With a `RIGHT JOIN` you will get additional values that would be excluded when using an `INNER JOIN`, because it will include all records from the "RIGHT" table. In this case, your sub-select, aliased a 'C'.

And one of those additional values is `a3` which can not be converted to an integer.

Comment: But problem is with INNER JOIN, not RIGHT JOIN.